# aggregating sums for specific time but would like to have multiple times in the same query

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to sum the number of orders for two years and have them side-by-side but am not sure how to do this. To summarize one year, I currently have:

```
select menu_item_id, 
       menu_item_header, 
       sum(quantity) 
from line_items 
where order_id in ( select id 
                    from orders 
                    where menu_id=807 
                      and stripe_transaction_state='paid' 
                      and created_at between '2019-01-01' 
                                         and '2020-01-01' ) 
group by menu_item_id, menu_item_header order by menu_item_id;
```

which gives me:

```
| menu_item_id | menu_item_header    | sum |
|--------------|---------------------|-----| 
| 21562        | bacon-wrapped dates |  82 |
```

but would like

```
| menu_item_id | menu_item_header    | sum 2018 | sum 2019 |
|--------------|---------------------|---------|----------| 
| 21562        | bacon-wrapped dates |  82     | 103      |
```

One problem is that the menu_item_header can be different? Is there a way that I can take the first one and ignore the rest? I could also join it to the menu_items table too.

How would I do this?

Comment: Unrelated, but: are you aware that you query will include rows from `2020-01-01`?

Comment: thx @a_horse_with_no_name - yes - was aware but appreciate you pointing out to me. It was just a thanksgiving menu which is last week of November

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select menu_item_id, 
       menu_item_header, 
       sum( case when created_at between '2018-01-01' 
                                     and '2018-12-31'
                 then quantity
                 end ) sum_2018,
       sum( case when created_at between '2019-01-01' 
                                     and '2019-12-31'
                 then quantity
                 end ) sum_2019
from line_items 
where order_id in ( select id 
                    from orders 
                    where menu_id=807 
                      and stripe_transaction_state='paid' 
                      and created_at between '2018-01-01' 
                                         and '2019-12-31' ) 
group by menu_item_id, 
         menu_item_header 
order by menu_item_id;
```

Comment: that's awesome - thx Akina